# How to use a very long JSON as text parameter in Power Shell?

Tags: powershell, stored-procedures, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps, azure-automation

TL;DR: I'm overflowing a string parameter with an over 500k character JSON.

I'm using an Azure based solution to:

1. In Logic Apps, go through a list of SharePoint Lists stored in over 200 SharePoint subsites.
2. Send HTTP Request to SharePoint API and download each list as JSON.
3. Call a Stored Procedure on SQL Database that transforms and loads the data to the database.

After having some issues with step 3, namely, timeout issues with the connection between Logic Apps, I've added step:

2.5: Call an Automation Runbook that calls the Stored Procedure without timing out. This is based on this [solution](https://connectedcircuits.blog/2018/11/25/using-azure-logic-app-and-an-automation-runbook-to-execute-a-long-running-sql-stored-procedure/). Basically, it's a PowerShell script that creates an ADO.NET connection with the Azure SQL Database and then executes the Stored Procedure, with the SP parameters being in turn requested as parameters in Logic Apps. Like this:

[image]

But with a few of the lists I'm getting an error indicating that I've busted the character limit on a PowerShell string variable:

```
{
  "code": "BadRequest",
  "message": "{\"Message\":\"The request is invalid.\",\"ModelState\":{\"job.properties.parameters\":[\"Job parameter values too long. Max allowed length:524288. Parameter names: Json\"]}}"
}
```

Here's the core of it: "Job parameter values too long. Max allowed length:524288. Parameter names: Json". This Parameter is declared on Power Shell as follows:

```
[parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
[string] $Json,
```

Is there another data type I could declare for this that would not run into this limitation?

Comment: you could dump it to file, would make more sense, probably. but seeing you hit the 524288 character limit, I'm pretty sure you are doing things wrong ;)

Comment: Yes.  You can save the file to Blob storage, and pass the uri to Azure SQL Database.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft 
Thanks for the reply!
How can I use import the blob content as flat text? Since my SP already reads the JSON parameter as text, on first look the methods described on the link you referenced (OPENROWSET, BULK INSERT) don't seem very promissing for this end.

Comment: @4c74356b41 Thanks for the reply! Yeah, the JSONs ar large because they contain whole tables. I'll try to push them into files.

Comment: In the doc I linked follow the example that uses the `SINGLE_CLOB` parameter.  That will return the full file contents in a single NVarchar(max) column.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the suggestion by David Browne on the comments, I passed my large JSON responses from the SharePoint API into a Blob Storage, and then passed the blob SAS URI as the parameter for the Stored Procedure. I also hade some Authorization issues executing this procedure and the solution my boss pointed to me was to create a Master Key. This was executed once:

```
USE ***DataBase***
GO
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '123'
GO
```

And then on the stored procedure, the part concerned with opening the Blob content and reading it into a table variable and finally into a text variable, was wrapped in a OPEN MASTER KEY - CLOSE MASTER KEY:

```
SET @vURI = '***Json BLOB URI***'
SET @SplitChar = CHARINDEX('?', @vURI)
SET @vFileName = REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@vURI, 1, @SplitChar -1),'https://***StorageAcc***.blob.core.windows.net/***ContainterName***/','')

OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '123'  

SET @vSQL = 'ALTER DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL dbscopedcredential WITH IDENTITY = ''SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE'',
            SECRET = ''***BLOB AUTHENTICATION***'';'
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @vSQL    

SET @vSQL = '
        DECLARE @vTable TABLE (BulkColumn NVARCHAR(MAX));
        INSERT INTO @vTable 
        SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
        BULK  ''' + @vFileName + ''',
        DATA_SOURCE = ''externaldatasource_import'', 
        SINGLE_CLOB) AS DataFile;
        SELECT * FROM @vTable
        '
INSERT INTO @vTable
EXEC sp_executesql @stmt = @vSQL

SELECT @vJson = [BulkColumn] FROM @vTable   

CLOSE MASTER KEY
```